# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined

Tags: angular, mongodb

I'm new to angular and mongodb. I'm trying to pull data from MongoDB and display it in an Angular Material Table. 
But i got a error

"ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined"

when i tried to open the app and the data from MongoDB won't load.
I manage to narrow down the problem that is something to do with this line.

```
return this.myservice.GetList().subscribe(res => this.dataSource.data = res["0"]["data"]);
                                                                                ^^^^^^^^
```

Thanks in advance!

**tabledata.component.ts**

```
import {BackendService} from './../backend.service';
import {Component, OnInit, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import {MatPaginator} from '@angular/material/paginator';
import {MatSort} from '@angular/material/sort';
import {MatTableDataSource} from '@angular/material/table';


@Component({
  selector: 'tabledata',
  templateUrl: './tabledata.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./tabledata.component.css']
})

export class TabledataComponent implements OnInit {
  displayedColumns = ['S_NAME', 'S_ADD', 'S_STATUS'];
  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource();

  @ViewChild(MatPaginator, {static: true}) paginator: MatPaginator;
  @ViewChild(MatSort, {static: true}) sort: MatSort;

  constructor(private myservice: BackendService) {
  }



  ngOnInit() {

    return this.myservice.GetList().subscribe(res => this.dataSource.data = res["0"]["data"]);

  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
  }

  applyFilter(filterValue: string) {
    this.dataSource.filter = filterValue.trim().toLowerCase();

    if (this.dataSource.paginator) {
      this.dataSource.paginator.firstPage();
    }
  }
}
```

**MongoDB Data in sitelist Collection**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ec4672e44f01dcae82c3dde"),
    "error" : "0",
    "num_rows" : 3,
    "data" : [ 
        {
            "S_NAME" : "SBOBETH",
            "S_ADD" : "sbobeth.com",
            "S_STATUS" : "UP"
        }, 
        {
            "S_NAME" : "GTRCASINO",
            "S_ADD" : "gtrcasino.com",
            "S_STATUS" : "DOWN"
        }, 
        {
            "S_NAME" : "SBOBETH",
            "S_ADD" : "sbobeth.com",
            "S_STATUS" : "DOWN"
        }, 
        {
            "S_NAME" : "GTRBETCLUB",
            "S_ADD" : "gtrbetclub.com",
            "S_STATUS" : "UP"
        }, 
        {
            "S_NAME" : "77UP",
            "S_ADD" : "77up.bet.com",
            "S_STATUS" : "UP"
        }, 
        {
            "S_NAME" : "DATABET88",
            "S_ADD" : "databet88.net",
            "S_STATUS" : "DOWN"
        }, 
        {
            "S_NAME" : "FAFA855",
            "S_ADD" : "fafa855.com",
            "S_STATUS" : "UP"
        }
    ]
}
```

**backend.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpResponse, HttpHeaders, HttpRequest  } from "@angular/common/http";
import { catchError, map, tap,  } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class BackendService {

  constructor(private _http: HttpClient) { }

  GetList() 
  {

    return this._http.get('http://localhost:3000/api/getList')

  }

  private handleError<T>(operation = 'operation', result?: T)
  {
    console.log("error");
    return null;
  }

  private log(message: string)
  {
    console.log("log");
  }

}
```

**server.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
require('./db')                                                                         
const SLDBModel = require('./sldbreply_schema');                                        

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }))

app.use(function (req, res, next)
{
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','*');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods','GET, POST, PUT, DELETE');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers','content-type, x-access-token');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
    next();
});

app.get('/api/getList', function(req, res){
    SLDBModel.find({},function(err,data){
        if(err)
        {
            res.send(err);
        }
        else
        {
            res.send(data);
        }
    });
})

app.listen(3000, ()=>
{
    console.log("SERVER IS ONLINE!");
})
```

After i tried console.log(res); from suggestion in the comment to check my 'res' data first.

[image]

and from server.js i tried console.log(data);

[image]

Both of them return [] not sure what this mean
Any suggestion on how to fix?

Comment: Whats the response data? If it as described in "MongoDB Data in sitelist Collection", then this object is not a list. res[0] you want res["data"][0] to get the first result

Comment: Check if your res["0"] contains a key name ddata, probably the response data has issue. Check the GetList service for the data it is returning.

Comment: I think you're right that my mongo collection is the problem. 
i tried console.log(res); but it don't reply me anything

Answer (score 1):

Inside **ngOnInit()** replace

```
return this.myservice.GetList().subscribe(res => this.dataSource.data = res["0"]["data"]);
```

with

```
this.myservice.GetList().subscribe(res => {
        console.log(res); // Check your 'res' data first
        dataSource.data = res["0"]["data"];
    });
```

Note: console your **res** to know how is your response data.

Comment: console.log(res); return [] please look at my new screenshot

Comment: In your service replace 
"return this._http.get('http://localhost:3000/api/getList')"
with 
"return this._http.get('http://localhost:3000/api/getList').map(res => res.json());"

and console again.
Please share the result in text instead of sharing screenshots.

Comment: Oh sorry it my first time asking here.
the error would occur at .map 
Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Observable<Object>'.

Comment: import 'rxjs/Rx'; in service

Comment: import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
the same error would still occur

Answer (score 0):

It appears the `data` property is the parent level of the object. Try the following in the `ngOnInit()`

```js
ngOnInit() {
  this.myservice.GetList().subscribe(
    res => { 
      this.dataSource.data = res['data'];
    },
    error => { 
      // always good practice to handle error in HTTP observables
    }
  );
}
```

Comment: It reply 
"ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined"

Comment: Could you please post the code where the `length` property is accessed?

Comment: Please check the code again. The error message is **Cannot read property _'length'_**.

Comment: The `length` property is from Standard built-in objects of Array.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Comment: It is used to access the length of an array in user applications. And from the screenshot it appears the array is empty. You need to verify how the data is accessed from the backend and if the backend sends the correct data. And go through Angular Tour of Heroes tutorial. It introduces some basics of Angular.

Answer (score 0):

Try converting data to Json on your server side as well

```
app.get('/api/getList', function(req, res){
SLDBModel.find({},function(err,data){
    if(err)
    {
        res.send(err);
    }
    else
    {
        res.send(data.toJSON());
    }
   });
})
```

Try console.log(data) as well.If it is an array please replace `res.send(data)` by `res.send(data.map(v => v.toJSON())`

Comment: console.log(data) return 
[] 
see my new screenshot